# How can I compare the a variable in different instances of the same class?

Tags: c++

I need to compare the variable that is stored in two different instances of the same class and it must return a bool.

I am trying to compare the ages of pepper and salty but not sure how to go about it. 
This is the first time I post so if its not clear let me now. I would like to learn how to use this page for help and learning.

someone mentioned using the 'this' pointer not sure how that would work.

```
class dog
{
 dog();
 dog(int yearsOld);

 bool sameAge(const dog& compareAge);

private:
 int yearsOld;
}

dog pepper(7);
dog salty(9);

bool dog::sameAge(const dog& compareAge)
{
 if(yearsOld == compareAge.yearsOld)
 {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}



sameAge(salty)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "two different child classes"? There are no parent and child classes here, just one class `dog`. And both objects are in the same class.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. Those are not "child classes" they are two different **instances** if the same *class dog*.

Comment: Thanks the correction  Galik. I still have the issue with how to code this correctly doe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison code is fine. The problem is that you're not calling the function correctly. You need to call the member function through an object. Otherwise, how will it know that it should be comparing with `pepper`?

```
if (pepper.sameAge(salty)) {
    // do something
}
```

This is basic to all object-oriented programming -- methods are called through objects.

Comment: Yes that is what I was Missing. 
I placed this in my Main.cpp file.
Of course my assignment is much more complicated, but this was the missing piece. 
I thank you once again sir. @Barmar
    pepper.sameAge(salty)